# Triggering Django management command with post_save signal on multiple servers

Tags: python, django

I have created a model and post_save signal which will invoke a management command with something like this

```
from django.core import management
management.call_command('your_command', your_options)
```

In that management command, I have to restart a process. I have same 15 machines serving with similar django server.

If I change the model, post_save will be triggered on one of those machines and process will be started on that machine. However I want that post_save signal to be triggered in all machines. How can I do this?

Comment: That's not possible. The trigger will be executed on the machine handling the request. The other will not even know about the request.

Comment: Is there way to handle this? With some external process or application?

Comment: And frankly: if you have to restart a process on every data change you might want to rethink your architectural design.

Comment: Data change won't be frequent and large, just a mapping of process and machines and once we update that mapping, I want those processes to start in those machines. Idea is to avoid logging to all machines and restarting process separately.

Comment: Most likely you'll need to just change that command to send some signals down a web socket to a list of end points. I agree with the above though, worth a rethink.